# Else if menu java

Tags: java, if-statement, menu

I am trying to make a menu using else if but I can't get the menu to display on the screen. Im not sure what I did wrong. (also, I have to use else if for this. cannot use switch as it has not been covered in my course yet). Any suggestions on what I have done wrong would be greatly appreciated.

public class ProcessorApp{

```
 public static void main(String args[]){ 

    int min; 
    String repeat="";

    
    Scanner Keyboard= new Scanner(System.in); 
    choice = Keyboard.nextInt(); 

    ratingProcessor myratingProcessor = new Processor(); //

    do {
        System.out.println("Application Menu ");
        System.out.println("1. blah blah");
        System.out.println("2. blah blah");
        System.out.println("3. blah blah");
        System.out.println("4. blah blah"); 
        System.out.println("5. blah blah"); 
        System.out.println("6. blah blah"); 
        System.out.println("7. Exit application");

        System.out.println("Enter Choice: ");

        //while((choice)!=7); //if choice is not 7 menu will repeat
            if (choice ==1){ 

            } else if(choice == 2) {

            } else if(choice == 3) {

            } else if(choice == 4) {

            } else if(choice == 5) {

            } else if(choice == 6) {

            } else if(choice == 7) {

            } else {
                  System.out.println("You did not chose a valid entry");
            }

        }

        while (repeat.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should move the Keyboard.nextInt() line to the line after where the menu is printed

```
int min;
    String repeat = "";


    Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    ratingProcessor myratingProcessor = new Processor(); //


    do {
        System.out.println("Application Menu ");
        System.out.println("1. blah blah");
        System.out.println("2. blah blah");
        System.out.println("3. blah blah");
        System.out.println("4. blah blah");
        System.out.println("5. blah blah");
        System.out.println("6. blah blah");
        System.out.println("7. Exit application");

        System.out.println("Enter Choice: ");

        //while((choice)!=7); //if choice is not 7 menu will repeat

        int choice = Keyboard.nextInt(); // This is where it should be

        if (choice == 1) {
        } else if (choice == 2) {
        } else if (choice == 3) {
        } else if (choice == 4) {
        } else if (choice == 5) {
        } else if (choice == 6) {
        } else if (choice == 7) {
        } else {
            System.out.println("You did not chose a valid entry");
        }

    }

    while (repeat.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this line:

```java
int choice = Keyboard.nextInt();
```

under this one:

```java
System.out.println("Enter Choice: ");
```

and you will see your menu.

You have put the keyboard input too early, before the do-while that shows the menu.

**P.S.** The condition inside the do-while loop is always false because `repeat` is an empty string, it's not "Yes" and it never changes.